# Images not storing to database

Tags: iphone, json, uiimageview, nsdata

I stored some images in my server. And try to get this images from URL and store to local database then try to access. But the images are not storing to database. But when i use log it displaying inserting all the values. But i can't shown in db via SQLiteManager

code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30)];

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];



}
```

Button click:

```
-(void)click:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"click");

 NSString *databasePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"db1" ofType:@"sqlite"];


    NSError *err=nil;
    NSFileManager *fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *arrPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, -1);
    NSString *path=[arrPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path2= [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];


     bool success=[fm copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:path2 error:&err];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"file copied successfully");
    }


    /*
    if(![fm fileExistsAtPath:path2])
    {

        bool success=[fm copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:path2 error:&err];
        if(success)
            NSLog(@"file copied successfully");
        else
            NSLog(@"file not copied");

    }
*/

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.net/projects/mobile/jsonstring.php"];



    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"response is %@", stringFromFileAtURL);

  //  NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
    //NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


    NSString *path1 = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];

    //NSDictionary *jsonDict = [stringFromFileAtURL JSONValue];


    //array

    NSArray *userData = [stringFromFileAtURL JSONValue];
    [stringFromFileAtURL release];

    int  i = 0;
    BOOL notExist = TRUE;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;


    for (NSArray *skarray in userData) {
        //NSLog(@"test");


        if(i == 0){
            //insert all main category
            for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {

                //write all this in the table
                //if already exists in data base id then overwrite the name

                //category table
                //NSLog(@"CategoryId is %@",[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_id"]);
                //NSLog(@"CategoryName is %@",[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"]);

                if (sqlite3_open([path1 UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

                    const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM categories where id = '%@'",[tuser objectForKey:@"id"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    NSLog(@"categories select is %s", sql);

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                        notExist = TRUE;

                        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                            notExist = FALSE;

                        }

                    }



                    if(notExist){
                        //NSLog(@"cat id does not exist");

                        const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into categories (id,cat_name,order_by) values('%@','%@','%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"id"], [tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"],[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                        NSLog(@"categories insert is %s", sqlInsert);

                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                        if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(addStmt))



                            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                    }




                }



            }
        }

        if(i == 1){
            //insert all main category
            for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {

                //write all this in the table
                //if already exists in data base id then overwrite the name

                //category table
                //NSLog(@"CategoryId is %@",[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_id"]);
                //NSLog(@"CategoryName is %@",[tuser objectForKey:@"cat_name"]);

                if (sqlite3_open([path1 UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

                    const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT product_image FROM product where cat_id = '%@'",[tuser objectForKey:@"id"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    // NSLog(@"product select is %s", sql);

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                        notExist = TRUE;

                        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                            notExist = FALSE;

                        }

                    }




                    if(notExist){
                        //NSLog(@"cat id does not exist");


                      //  imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([tuser objectForKey:@"product_image"]);

                        //  sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 6, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);


                        const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into product (id, cat_id,product_image,order_by) values ('%@','%@','%@','%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"id"], [tuser objectForKey:@"cat_id"],[tuser objectForKey:@"product_image"],[tuser objectForKey:@"order_by"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                        NSLog(@"product insert %s", sqlInsert);

                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



                        if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



                    }



                }



            }
        }



        if(i == 2){
            //insert all main category
            for (NSDictionary *tuser in skarray) {

                NSLog(@"version id is %@",[tuser objectForKey:@"product_id"]);

                const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into version_app (id) values ('%@')", [tuser objectForKey:@"product_id"]] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];




                NSLog(@"stmt is %s", sqlInsert);

                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            }
        }

        i++;

    }

    }
```

Comment: What happens if the DB fails to open?

Comment: @How Licks: How to check DB fails?

Comment: Read the spec.  That's why it's provided.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything wrong here:

```
 bool success=[fm copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:path2 error:&err];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"file copied successfully");
}
```

Comment: Yes. Im getting file copied successfully while !success case.

Comment: @Hot Licks:I got it. But the data is not inserting to database. Im getting NSLog in all values. But why it's not storing to database (db1.sqlite) file

Comment: @user2674668 - Did you read the spec???  copyItemAtPath returns YES if successful.  You print "file copied successfully" if the return value was NO, then don't check/print the error value at all.  Read the spec.

Comment: The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) for the iOS interfaces.  The [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) for SQLite.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a service where others do your research for you.